# What's the word for when water smashes against an obstacle and is forced around it?

Tags: verbs

I know there probably isn’t one word that covers that entire experience (although if there is, I’m definitely interested). I mainly want to know what the word is for when water is forced around. For example, when you hit water with your hand and it splashes water out. What is that splashing called? The best I can come up with is scattering, but I don’t like it.

Example sentence: The water smashed against the rock and scattered around it.

Is there a better word than scatter?

I know I'm going to be asked if I did any research. I tried, but because I can't figure out the word I'm looking for--although it's on the tip of my tongue--I can't figure out what to search for.

Comment: When I hit the water with my hand for the purpose of directing the displaced water onto someone they, they just say "Quit splashing."  You can also get hit by "spray" coming off the rocks after a wave hits it or near the bottom of a waterfall.

Comment: Water flows over or around or under a rock.  That said, water does not scatter.

Comment: The water smashed against the rock and **flowed/surged** around it.

Comment: There's a big difference between water hitting something (like a sea wall) and sending lots of spray in the air, and water flowing around something (like a rock or a person's legs).

Answer (score 1):

I'll say the word is **displacement**. Edit: If the water hits something and moves around, it could be **diverted**, **channeled**, or **rerouted**.

From [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/video/181395/Discussion-forces-bodies-water#:%7E:text=When%20an%20object%20enters%20water,This%20is%20called%20displacement.): "When an object enters water, it pushes out water to make room for itself. The object pushes out a volume of water that is equal to its own volume. This is called displacement."

From Oxford: Diverted 1. cause (someone or something) to change course or turn from one direction to another. "a scheme to divert water from the river to irrigate agricultural land"

Comment: It doesn't really cover the case of water hitting an object and then flowing around it.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking of the reference to a hand hitting water and wound up answering that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Why a bot? Geesus, so annoying. Such a good answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

At least in your example, water, as a wave, diffracts.  I believe diffract would answer your question.

Comment: Or, possibly ripples.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Could you explain why you believe the word is suitable? Perhaps you could cite a definition or usage example that suggests it fits the question's needs.

Comment: Hello. I was thinking that the asker was looking for a specific word that focused on the "going around" aspect in relation to the obstacle.  This is the action of a wave in physical terms.  I probably was thinking too hard.

Comment: Oh no, I didn't mean to suggest that your answer is wrong at all. It's a great suggestion, imho. However it's beneficial to *persuade* voters to agree with you somehow (to earn + votes). And the best way is by providing some authoritative corroboration, using references and/or citing examples of usage. I'm voting it up, now that I have the opportunity to do so. I certainly would not have down-voted it: someone else did that. But I should have included this link in my first comment, because my intent is only to help and make you feel welcome: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Well, thank you, Bread.  I am still trying to understand the Stack exchanges and how they work.  I asked an astronomy question a week or so ago, and got such an immediate and excellent response that I was impressed.  So, I have been exploring how it works and trying to contribute a little.  It may take me a while to understand the ins and outs, so be patient.  I appreciate the information.

Comment: Patience is my middle name, :D Have courage, and be persistent -- I'm sure you'll do just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly surge around something, or slosh around something (both more forceful than the rippling and splashing in the other answers) the water can slosh around **in * something (like in a bucket that is being carried by someone running) or it can slosh around something, (like a wave sloshing around a stone at the beach) - as with the 'surge around something', no splashing (no droplets) are involved.

Answer (score 0):

The water **pounded** the rock, then **dispersed** into the ocean.

> https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pounded

*Nearly 50 people are still missing after the storm pounded the coast.*

> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disperse

*to cause to break up*

Answer (score 0):

**Impinge** would serve in a techie sense.

> PHYSICS
> strike.
> "the gases impinge on the surface of the liquid"
> [Google definiton of impinge](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+impinge&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS724US727&oq=define+impinge&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l4.8925j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: No. '... the word is for when water is forced around ....' Synonyms of _hit, strike_ are not a topic for ELU.

Answer (score 0):

According to the literature (like [this dissertation](https://mountainscholar.org/bitstream/handle/10217/185720/Zhou_colostate_0053A_14540.pdf?sequence=1)), water *shears* when it encounters an obstacle.

From M-W Unabridged:

> **shear**, *n.*
>
> **5a** : a strain resulting from applied forces that cause or tend to cause contiguous parts of a body to slide relatively to each other in
> a direction parallel to their plane of contact  specifically : the
> ratio of the relative displacement of these parts to the distance
> between them
>
> **5b**: the stress giving rise to this strain — see shearing stress

Comment: There is wind shear but I never heard of water shear...

Comment: @Lambie Same concept; both are fluids from a physical standpoint.